# missing components on SQL server 2016 installation

Tags: installation, sql

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2016 (Developer or Evaluation edition) to get familiar with it as I have not used it for several years.

Downloaded SQL Server Developer from Visual Studio Dev Essentials page ( https://myprodscussu1.app.vssubscriptions.visualstudio.com/Benefits) and later the evaluation edition from  the Evaluation Center:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016

Attempting installation on Windows Server 2008 R2 Evaluation copy installed on VMWare ESXi 5.1 Virtual machine.

When the installer gets to the Feature Selection page I only see 2 possible components to install:

-Reporting Services - SharePoint

-Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products

I do not see any of the SQL Server core components.

I have the same issue with both the above installers and both packages are around 2.1 GB, so I would expect the whole product to be contained there.

Any feedback on what could be the problem greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Seeing as Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't appear to be listed as a supported OS, my suggestion would be to install it on a supported OS. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx